# How to close program if text document is not found

Tags: java

This is the top of my program. You are to type in a .txt file name for it to open.

Problem: How do I have the program display an error message and close the program if .txt file is not found?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Get the filename.
        System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
        // Open the file.
        //Runtime error is the file isn't found
        File file = new File(filename + ".txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: Look into [try-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) and [FileNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)

Comment: You may wish to explore a more user friendly approach and re-prompt the user for a different file name in case the original isn't found. Throwing the user out on his ear for making a mistake might be a fantasy common among programmers, but it doesn't make for good user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put File in try catch block like this and show a relevant message:

```
try{
    File file = new File(filename + ".txt");
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.print("exception occur exception message= " +e.getMessage());
}
```